# Format note-count/numbers 1000 = 1k while targeting all divs of same class

Tags: javascript

This piece of script has been passed around on Tumblr for years, to shorten the display note-count on blog posts:

```
var $container = $(".content");
$container.find(".notecount").each(function () {
    var n = $(this).html().split(" ")[0].replace(/,/g, "");
    if (n > 999) {
        n = Math.floor(n / 100) / 10;
        $(this).text(n + "k notes");
    }
});
```

I'm fairly new-ish to js, but I find it a bit overkill to implement jquery to change (up to) 15 numbers on a page just for that neat trick, and was wondering if I could do without.

The following is mostly adapted from [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/amRbVo) but 1, I know it's only affecting the first class on every page (I tried `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelectorAll`) and 2, my gauge is that I possibly will need to loop it - don't know how to loop the function so I'm questioning whether or not that's doable as is:

```
var tnotes = document.querySelector(".notecount");

function ShortenIt(value) {
    var retVal = "";
    if (value < 2) {
        retVal = String(value) + " note";
    }

    if (value >= 2 && value < 1000) {
        retVal = value + " notes";
    }

    if (value >= 1000 && value < 1000000) {
        retVal = Math.round(value / 1000) + "k notes";
    }

    if (value >= 1000000 && value < 1000000000) {
        retVal = Math.round(value / 1000000) + "m notes";
    }

    tnotes.innerHTML = retVal;
}

ShortenIt(tnotes.innerText);
```

Structure of each post:

```
<article class="post {PostType}" id="{PostID}">
<div>post content</div>

<div class="info">
<div class="notecount"><a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount}</a></div>
</div>

</article>
```

I've gone through quite a few questions/answers on here, but I either came up short, or, still had trouble with targeting only the note count and not random numbers in a blog post. Any help or direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of those jQuery methods are available in vanilla JS in one form or another (jQuery, after all, is just an abstraction on top of these DOM manipulation methods). Check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for some common ways to iterate over an array.

```js
const convertNoteCounts = () => {
  // querySelectorAll returns a NodeList...
  const myListOfElements = document.querySelectorAll(".notecount");

  // ... so we'll convert it to an Array and iterate over it
  Array.from(myListOfElements).forEach((noteCountEl) => {
    // grab the first child, which in our DOM will always be an <a /> element
    let element = noteCountEl.children[0];
    let n = Number(element.innerText.split(" ")[0].replace(/,/g, ""));
    if (n > 999) {
      n = Math.floor(n / 100) / 10;
      element.innerText = `${n}k`;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<article class="post {PostType}" id="{PostID}">
<div>post content</div>

<div class="info">
  <div class="notecount"><a href="#">863</a></div>
  <div class="notecount"><a href="#">102</a></div>
  <div class="notecount"><a href="#">1,400</a></div>
  <div class="notecount"><a href="#">9,459</a></div>
  <div class="notecount"><a href="#">12,450</a></div>
</div>
<button onclick="convertNoteCounts()">Convert!</button>

</article>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Would totally work everywhere else, except, I seem to be limited by Tumblr's own variables - everything between `{}` will be rendered irrelevant and removed if it doesn't fit one of their variables. The output right now is simply `$k notes`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "everything between {} will be rendered irrelevant and removed if it doesn't fit one of their variables." Perhaps you mean if it doesn't fit their DOM scheme (i.e. it doesn't match the way they've set up their HTML elements)? I've updated my answer to match the DOM from your post more closely, see if that helps get you on the right track.

Comment: Nevermind, a space between so it's `${ n }k` stops Tumblr from reading it as one of their variables. It works as it should. Again, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please accept this answer if you don't have any more questions